# How do I delete the current line based on a match in both the previous and current lines in sed?

Tags: unix, sed

Given a sorted file like so:

```
AAA 1 2 3
AAA 2 3 4
AAA 3 4 2
BBB 1 1 1
BBB 1 2 1
```

and a desired output of

```
AAA 1 2 3
BBB 1 1 1
```

what's the best way to achieve this with sed?

Basically, if the col starts with the same field as the previous line, how do I delete it? The rest of the data must be kept on the output.

I imagine there must be some way to do this either using the hold buffer, branching, or the test command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another way with awk:

```
awk '!($1 in a){print;a[$1]}' file
```

Comment: Interesting, but not quite what was asked for in that if the sixth line was `AAA 5 6 7`, the question would expect it to be printed, but your code would not because `AAA` was seen once before.  (But, since this was accepted, who knows; maybe I misunderstood the question.)

Comment: Updated question to reflect that yes, the files are sorted. Sorry about that

Comment: One more question: are they sorted only on the first column?

Comment: It is much more idiomatic to write `awk '!a[$1]++'`

Answer (score 1):

This could be done with AWK:

```
$ gawk '{if (last != $1) print; last = $1}' in.txt
AAA 1 2 3
BBB 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's a simpler way with `sed`, but:

```
sed ':a;N;/\([[:alnum:]]*[[:space:]]\).*\n\1/{s/\n.*//;ta};P;D'
```

This produces the output

```
AAA 1 2 3
BBB 1 1 1
```

which differs from that in the question, but matches the description:

> if the col starts with the same field as the previous line, how do I delete it?

Comment: Output was wrong, updated. Your sed expression just returns every line though with my test data.

Comment: @Dinedal Then post your test data. I used those from the question. If it doesn't work on your system with the data from the question, then what system is it? OS X, maybe?

Comment: It is OS X. That's probably why, a mismatch of engines or something.

Comment: IIRC I don't think that :alnum: and :space: are supported

Comment: @Dinedal I've never used `sed` on OS X, but I know it differs from the Linux version. I'm not sure what should be changed. If anyone can add an OS X-compatible version of the script, please feel free to. P.S. Google says the char classes are supported, FWIU.

Comment: I recommend `gsed` from MacPorts for good(TM) tools on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;$!N;s/^((\S+\s).*)\n\2.*/\1/;ta;P;D' file
```

or maybe just:

```
sort -uk1,1 file
```

Answer (score 0):

One way using `GNU awk`:

```
awk '!array[$1]++' file.txt
```

Results:

```
AAA 1 2 3
BBB 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sed:

```
#!/bin/sed -nf

P

: loop
s/\s.*//
N
/\([^\n][^\n]*\)\n\1/ b loop

D
```

Firstly, we must pass the `-n` flag to sed so it will only print what we tell it to.

We start off by printing the line with the "P" command, because the first line will always be printed and we will force sed to only execute this line when we want it to.

Now we will do a loop. We define a loop with a starting label through the ":" command (in this case we name the label as "loop"), and when necessary we jump back to this label with a "b" command (or a "t" test command). This loop is quite simple:

1. Remove everything but the first field (replace the first space character and everything that follows it with nothing)
2. Append the next line (a newline character will be included)
3. Check if the new line starts with the field we isolated. We do this by using a capture. A capture is defined as a "sub-match" whose matched input will be stored into a special "variable", named numerically following the order of captures present. We specify captures using parenthesis escaped with backslased (starts with `\(` and ends with `\)`). In this case we match all characters that aren't a newline character (ie. `[^\n]`) up to the end of the line. We do this by matching at least one of non-newline characters followed by an arbitrary sequence of them. This prevents matching an empty string before a newline. After the capture, we match a newline character followed by the result of the capture, by using the special variable `\1`, which contains the input matched by that first capture. If this succeeds, we have a line that repeats the first field, so we jump back to the start of the loop with the "b" branch command.
4. When we exit the loop, we have found a line that has a different first field, so we must prepare the input line and jump back to the beginning of the script. This can be done with the "D" delete-first-line-and-restart-script command.

This can be shortened into a single line (notice that we have renamed the "loop" label into "a"):

```
sed -e 'P;:a;s/\s.*//;N;/\([^\n][^\n]*\)\n\1/ba;D'
```